# Autowired failed and Bean Creation Error

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

**I'm trying to implement simple CRUD operation with Spring-Hibernate.**

**Here is my EmployeeServieImpl file**

```
package com.kalam.serviceimpl;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.kalam.dao.EmployeeDao;
import com.kalam.daoimpl.EmployeeDaoImpl;
import com.kalam.model.Employee;
import com.kalam.service.EmployeeService;

@Service("employeeService")
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.SUPPORTS,rollbackFor=Exception.class)
public class EmployeeServiceImpl implements EmployeeService{


    @Autowired
    EmployeeDao employeeDao;

    public void addEmployee(Employee emp) {
        employeeDao.addEmployee(emp);

    }

    public void updateEmployee(Employee emp) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void deleteEmployee(Employee emp, int id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

**EmployeeDaoImpl class**

```
package com.kalam.daoimpl;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.kalam.dao.EmployeeDao;
import com.kalam.model.Employee;

@Repository("employeeDao")
public class EmployeeDaoImpl implements EmployeeDao {
    @Autowired
     SessionFactory sessionFactory;


    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }



    public void addEmployee(Employee emp) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction tx= session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(emp);
        tx.commit();
        session.close();
    }



    public void updateEmployee(Employee emp) {
         Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
          session.beginTransaction();
            session.update(emp);
            session.getTransaction().commit();

    }



    public void deleteEmployee(Employee emp, int id) {
         Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
          session.beginTransaction();
            Employee employee = (Employee) session.get(Employee.class, new Integer(id));
            if(null != employee){
                session.delete(emp);
                                }
       session.getTransaction().commit();

    }

}
```

**Controller File**

```
package com.kalam.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.kalam.daoimpl.EmployeeDaoImpl;
import com.kalam.model.Employee;
import com.kalam.service.EmployeeService;



@Controller
@RequestMapping("/hello")
public class KalamController {

@Autowired
EmployeeService employeeService;

    @RequestMapping("/kalam")
    public String showMessage(ModelMap map) {

        map.put("dollar", "50 US $");
        return "KalamWorld";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/insertData",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public void InserData() {

        Employee emp= new Employee();
        emp.setEmpID(11);
        emp.setEmpName("On Target");
        emp.setEmpSalary(20000);
        emp.setAddress("Mumbai");


        employeeService.addEmployee(emp);  
    } 

}
```

**And finally hibernate configuration class.**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"  
 xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
 xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

<!-- Activate Spring annotation support -->
<context:annotation-config />

<mvc:annotation-driven /> 

<context:component-scan base-package="com.kalam.controller" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.kalam.serviceimpl"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.kalam.daoimpl"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.kalam.model"/>

<!-- DataSource configurationt -->
 <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">  
        <property name="driverClassName"  value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>  
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/kalamdb"></property>  
        <property name="username" value="root"></property>  
        <property name="password" value="root"></property>  
    </bean>  

   <bean id="sessionFactory"  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">  
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>  

        <property name="mappingResources">  
        <list>  
        <value>employee.hbm.xml</value>  
        </list>  
        </property>  

        <property name="hibernateProperties">  
            <props>  
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>  
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>  
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>  
            </props>  
        </property>  
    </bean>





     <bean id="transactionManager"
              class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
              <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
       </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />



    </beans>
```

**When i run the program i got the following errors.**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'kalamController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.kalam.service.EmployeeService com.kalam.controller.KalamController.employeeService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.kalam.service.EmployeeService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:700)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5110)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5633)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1694)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1684)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.kalam.service.EmployeeService com.kalam.controller.KalamController.employeeService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.kalam.service.EmployeeService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.kalam.service.EmployeeService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1100)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:960)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:855)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
    ... 24 more
```

**Please tell me why i'm getting such errors. Also can you tell me the difference between xml and annotaion configuration with example. Please provide any useful link or stuff. Thank you in advance.**

Answer (score 0):

You didn't define `EmployeeService` as Spring bean (marked as `@Component` , `@Service` ,....).

Seems that you should try to inject `EmployeeServiceImpl` inside the controller (or anywhere you need) instead of `EmployeeService`.
Or
post your `EmployeeService` here to see what we can do.

Maybe if you replace `<context:component-scan base-package="com.kalam.controller" />` with `<context:component-scan base-package="com.kalam.*" />` and remove other `<context:component-scan>` you got fine. (perhaps your interface is in another package that you didn't add to component scan).

Comment: i did change as per your suggestion. still getting same error.